# Convert bigint to Month Day, Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to convert bigint I read from SQL Server database to date in Month day, Year.

Instead, the query outputs Month day, Year hour:minute

```
CAST (DATEADD(SECOND, bigintcolumn /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') AS VARCHAR(50)) as Last_Checkin
```

Will output May 20 2015  3:53AM, instead of May 20 2015

I tried

```
CAST (DATEADD(SECOND, SEM_AGENT.LAST_UPDATE_TIME /1000 + 8*60*60, 107) AS VARCHAR(50)) as Last_Checkin
```

And it gave strange results, i.e. instead of May 20 2015  3:53AM it gave Sep  4 1945  3:53AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(30), 
                Dateadd(SECOND, bigintcolumn / 1000 + 8 * 60 * 60, '19700101'), 
                107) AS Last_Checkin
```